# What does a person started to plateau mean?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

The following sentence is quoted from a transcript of [NBC NEWS](https://www.nbcnews.com/meet-the-press/meet-press-11-08-20-n1247045). Mr. Jim Clyburn said:

> ... But I can tell you about the 1st congressional district of South Carolina. I really believe that that's what cost Joe Cunningham his seat. And I can also tell you about the Senate here in South Carolina. **Jaime Harrison started to plateau** when “defund the police” showed up with a caption on TV, ran across his head. That stuff hurt Jaime. And that's why I spoke out against it a long time ago. I've always said that these headlines can kill a political effort ...

What does a person started to plateau mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[American Heritage Dictionary "plateau"](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=plateau)

> intr.v.
> To reach a stable level; level off: *The tension seemed to grow by degrees, then it plateaued.*

A plateau is a raised area of ground with a flat top. The figurative use here means that the support for Harrison's campaign was rising, and then it stopped rising and stayed level, as a plateau does.